# Issue looping simple javascript slideshow with links

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I have a simple slideshow using javascript. I want to make the images linked and clickable. However, after the first loop, the images won't load in and I only get a white space with a border around it via my css… I would like the simple slideshow to work and load in each image.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="slides">
    <a href="http://www.google.de" target="_blank"><img src="images/sample_slides/test.jpg"alt="test"></a>
    <a><img src="images/sample_slides/test1.jpg" alt="test1"></a>
    <a><img src="images/sample_slides/test2.jpg" alt="test2"></a>
    <a><img src="images/sample_slides/test3.jpg" alt="test3"></a>
</div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){$('.slides img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){$('.slides :first-child').fadeOut('slow').next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.slides');}, 7000);});
</script>
```

Thank you for any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to hide and show the a tags since they're the new children of .slides. Something like:

```
$(function(){
    $('.slides a:gt(0)').hide();

    setInterval(function(){
      $('.slides a:first-child')
        .fadeOut('slow').next('a').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.slides');
    }, 7000);
});
```